# Axler: proving that the length o f a linearly independent list is less than or equal to the length of any spanning list

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, induction

Theorem 2.23 in Axler's book states:

> In a finite-dimensional vector space, the length of every linearly independent list of vectors is less than or equal to the length of every spanning list of vectors.

The proof proceeds by an algorithm. It takes a linearly independent list $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ and a spanning list $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ and seeks to prove $m \leq n$. Step 1 appends $u_1$ to the start of the list of $w$'s, argues that the resulting list still spans, and removes one of the $w$'s for redundancy. It then proceeds to step $j$ after having done step $j-1$.

My question is: is this in effect a "truncated" proof by induction? There are only $m$ choices for $u_i$, so I need $j \leq m$. In order to assume the result holds after step $j-1$, I need $j \geq 2$. So is the induction hypothesis "assume we've done this at step $j-1$ when $1 \leq j - 1 \leq m - 1$?"

I've never seen an induction proof when $j$ has a maximal possible value. Is this a totally different idea, or can I still call it proof by induction?

Comment: Yes, this is a proof by induction, at its heart. The (unknown) maximum $m$ on $j$ is not a big obstacle; all you need to do is assume in your induction step that $j < m$, so that there is a $j + 1$ step. In the case $j = m$, there is no need for an induction step, as the proof is done.

Comment: I would show that a spanning set has $\ge \dim V$ elements and a li set has $\le \dim V$ elements.

Comment: @copper.hat I think Axler uses this result to develop the well-definedness of $\dim V$, i.e. all bases are of the same length. I can't remember though; it's been too long since I read it.